# How do I count the number of objects (lists) in a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem with counting objects in a vector. The problem is that I have a column with ids, and a column of indicators (multiple choice answers). To deal with multiple choice I've put it into a vectorized value. Here is the example, which looks certainly like my data:

```
structure(list(id = c("000c6", 
"0016c", "00194", 
"00221", "0026e", 
"002fa", "0032a", 
"00331", "004ea", 
"00616"), indicators = list(c("1", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "-1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "-1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "-1", ""), c("", "0", 
"-1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "-1", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"), c("", "1", "1", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", ""), NULL, NULL, c("", "0", "-1", "0", "-1", "0", "-1", 
"-1", "1", "0", "-1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0", "-1", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "1", "", "", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", ""), c("1", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", ""), NULL, NULL, c("", "0", "1", "0", "1", "-1", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "-1", "1", "-1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "-1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "-1", "0", "-1", "0", "0", "0", "", 
"", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", ""))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to count the number of cells in `indicators`, where value is not `NULL`. How can I do that? The main difficulty for me is that `indicators` column contains vectors, not a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to get length of each element in `indicators` column.

```
lengths(df$indicators)
#[1]  86  21 215   0   0 172  43   0   0 215
```

We can now count the values which are greater than 0.

```
sum(lengths(df$indicators) > 0)
#[1] 6
```

---

Although you don't need a loop here but you can use also use `sapply` with `is.null` :

```
sum(!sapply(df$indicators, is.null))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using

- `length` + `Filter`

```
> length(Filter(length,df$indicators))
[1] 6
```

- `length` + `Filter`+`is.null`

```
> length(Filter(Negate(is.null),df$indicators))
[1] 6
```